# How to extract fraction numbers with decimals in numerator and/or denominator?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following function that finds the normal, decimal, and fraction numbers (and it keeps the leading zeros, and detects the sign of the numbers as I want to):

```py
def extract_numbers(text):
    numbers = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d*/\d+|[-+]?\d+",  text)
    return numbers
```

The **problem** occurs when I test it with a **fraction number that has decimals in the numerator or the denominator**:

```py
print(extract_numbers('this is difficult to get: -124.01/11.1'))
```

Output:

```
['-124.01', '/11', '.1']
```

When I need it to be like:

```
['-124.01/11.1']
```

So how to adjust the regex to extract the numbers with this prioritization:
**fraction numbers with decimals** then **fraction numbers** then **decimal numbers** and finally **normal numbers**

Comment: Could you give an example of the input text?

Comment: @KunalShah yes it is provided there, `'this is difficult to get: -124.01/11.1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:/\d*\.?\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WZg8cT/1). *Details*:

- `[-+]?` - an optional sign
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional period
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:/\d*\.?\d+)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `\d*\.?\d+` - zero or more digits, an optional period and one or more digits.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the following regular expression to extract the desired strings (when used with Python's [PyPi regex package](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)).

```
(?<!([.\d/]))-?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\/(?2))?(?!(?1))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYWDXK/1) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY/BboNADETv@xVmL7UV4mUXGpSo1V7bbwg5oLANSAkgLwf69RRQL9b4eTQjj79TO/T5snSvcZAJJDzCrFQtAp9w1Udn@Wxyx6VOQeelWfdik9/TW4R2mBLA4p0dNOEhIUTabva0za8gAboI7sS5sSUX9UY5s8btJnac78RmGeubUjKvlXs/34fX2D0Dikb/keCVq6YyN6Kjx6o5oL9UKzmQp00a9I7Io0/QWyJNCtTPIBCh62F95KIARun6CWP6nx9DLfcWZU4hEqll@QM)

The regex operates as follows.

```
(?<!          # begin negative lookbehind
  (           # begin capture group 1
    [.\d/]    # match one of the indicated characters
  )           # end capture group 1
)             # end negative lookbehind
-?            # optionally match '-'
(             # begin capture group 2
  \d+         # match 1+ digits
  (?:\.\d+)?  # optionally match '.' followed by 1+ digits 
)             # end capture group 2
(?:           # begin non-capture group
  \/          # match '/' 
  (?2)        # recurse subpattern 2
)?            # end non-capture group and make it optional
(?!           # begin negative lookahead
  (?1)        # recurse subpattern 1
)             # end negative lookahead
```

Notice at the links how the negative lookbehind at the beginning and the negative lookahead at the end avoid inappropriate matches.

I could have used Python's `re` module, at the expense of a longer regular expression, but chose to use Matthew Barnett's "regex package" to illustrate how [subroutines](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) can be used to simplify expressions. Note the "Regex demo" link uses the PCRE engine, which is similar to the PyPi regex engine.

The code that generates capture groups 1 and 2, and the code that later reuses that code is marked below.

```
(?<!([.\d/]))-?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\/(?2))?(?!(?1))
     111111     2222222222222      yyyy     xxxx
```

The reference `(?2)` causes `(?2)` to be replaced by `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` (not by the content of capture group 2). Similarly, `(?1)` is replaced by `[.\d/]`. Subroutines are also used for recursion but, as here, can simply be used to avoid repetition, thereby reducing errors and making expressions easier to read.

Comment: It worked too and also it avoided incorrectly formatted numbers like .100. but in some math scenarios, .100 could be considered 0.100 so I take this into consideration in my case of use

Comment: Just change `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to `\d*(?:\.\d+)?` to permit `'.100'` and similar.